# How do I solve this error message when I try to install Gatsby?

Tags: node.js, gatsby

```
adamlantz@student-212-160 ~ % npm i -g gatsby-cli
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'] {
npm ERR!   stack: "Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'",
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/adamlantz/.npm/_logs/2020-03-16T10_26_37_976Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Do you have permission to read and write to `usr/local/lib/node_modules`?

Comment: Yes! and it was solved thanks to Naor suggestion about using: "sudo npm i -g gatsby-cli" in Terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do that with sudo:

`sudo npm i -g gatsby-cli`